# Getting link using specific text

Tags: regex

From HTML body,I have to extract link which has text "Customer".For example

`<a href="google.com?x=1&xy=2" _target="blank" title="cus">Customer </a>`

I was thinking of using regex. What regex to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=\"(.*?)\".*>.*Customer.*</a>
```

Comment: this does not work.I am using vbscript for regular expressions